# FlatFile schema creation "out of order segment" error in mule 4

Tags: mule, schema, dataweave, anypoint-studio, flat-file

I am trying to parse a huge flat file into flat file schema, from a file if 3 rows contains tag value "2" then it should pick all three rows at a time but in my case, am unable to pick those rows whose tag values are similar but if it is in sequentially manner then i am able to pick if it is in different rows then it is unable to pick the rows and while parsing it throws error.

I want to pick all data along with all the data tag value starts with =2
all the tag value starts with= G

Please help me how can i achieve it?

```
1220612WEBL230PROD2206080606CA01                                         
200000162608361   FFVV220606D910142122982635 4TKTT0140MAZUR/JESSICA APRIL
500000100000071069CAD2CA      00000001425XG      00000003384SQ      00000
G000001YXY  YVR                      AC  K 03JUL22     06SEPKZ2HZCFL     
2000001CAD   657.60            CAD   710.690QYXY AC YVR Q3.00Q27.00 197.1
G000001                   00000000000      CAD2  CA                      
2000001AC ONLY -BG AC
```

Schema

```
form: FLATFILE

structures:
- id: 'ID'
  name: ID
  data:
  - { idRef: 'IT01', count: 1 }
  - { idRef: 'IT02', count: '>1' }
  - { idRef: 'IT05', count: '>1' }
  - { idRef: 'IT0G', count: '>1' }
  
segments:
- id: 'IT01'
  name: IFG RET file header
  values:
  - { name: 'recIdentifier', usage: M, type: String, length: 1, tagValue: '1' }
  - { name: 'sate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'fier', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'nt', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'ate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'ime', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Code', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 41 }
- id: 'IT02'
  name: IFG RET file IT02 record
  values:
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 1, tagValue: '2' }
  - { name: 'sate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'fier', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'nt', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'ate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'ime', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Code', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 41 }
- id: 'IT05'
  name: IFG RET file IT05 record
  values:
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 1, tagValue: '5' }
  - { name: 'sate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'fier', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'nt', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'ate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'ime', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Code', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 41 }
- id: 'IT0G'
  name: IFG RET file IT0G record
  values:
  - { name: 'recIdentifier', usage: M, type: String, length: 1, tagValue: 'G' }
  - { name: 'sate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'fier', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'nt', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'ate', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
  - { name: 'ime', usage: M, type: String, length: 4 }
  - { name: 'Code', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'Number', usage: M, type: String, length: 2 }
  - { name: 'notUsed1', usage: M, type: String, length: 41 }
```

Expected output-

```````````````
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "5": [
        {
          "Records": "      0000000",
          "hello3": "      00000000000"
          
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "After": "16DEC",
          "hello": "YYZ"
        }
      ],
 "Header": {   //how to generate this field in flat file schema please help me
          
  "1": {
    "reportingSystemIdentifier": "WEBL",
    "recIdentifier": "1"
    
  }
}
]
}
``````````````
```````````````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because the structure expects the order defined in the flat file schema (records 2, records 5, records G) but in the file line 5 has a record 2 after a record G.

If the records are in ordered groups of 2, 5, G you could try using a [group](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-flat-file-schemas#group-definitions) with repetitions.

However if the records are unordered, then the flat file format may not support such a structure. You may need to implement an alternative with code (Java or scripts).

Updating the structure with a group that contains records 2, 5 and G in that order may work. Just as an example:

```
...
structures:
- id: 'IFGRET'
  name: IFGRET
  data:
  - { idRef: 'IT01', count: 1 }
  - groupId: 'Details'
    count: '>1'
    items:
    - { idRef: 'IT02', count: '>1' }
    - { idRef: 'IT05', count: '>1' }
    - { idRef: 'IT0G', count: '>1' }
...
```

Comment: Hi @aled
Could you please help me with the grouping I am trying to group so that it will pick all the tagvalues together but am unable to do.
the records are in ordered groups of 2, 5, G. how to add grouping logic to the above schema. Please help me.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example. I can not test if it works as is or if you need to modify it further.

Comment: Hi @aled I have already tested with the above example in similar manner as you did but it is not working. how did you give details as a group id? any specific rule to add group id ?

Comment: Hi @aled Thank you so much the above code works I tested with the above example it is working. how did you give details as a group id? any specific rule to add group id ? and I wanted if it is IT02 then under that all the tag value related to "2" should display but here everything is separate array. is there any way to combine it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. However if the original question is answered I recommend to accept/upvote the answer and ask a new question providing more context and examples.

Comment: Hi @aled I also want to add a header tag along with group id. is it possible i have updated my output is it possible to add ?
expected output-
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "5": [
        {
          "Records": "      0000000",
          "hello3": "      00000000000"
          
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "After": "16DEC",
          "hello": "YYZ"
        }
      ],
 "Header": {   //how to generate this field in flat file schema please help me
          
  "1": {
    "reportingSystemIdentifier": "WEBL",
    "recIdentifier": "1"
    
  }
}
]
}

Comment: I was trying to add a new question but it wasn't allowing me as it had some error while posting the question hence please help with this. I have edited my epected above in the question